# Index out of bounds in Bitmap.SetSourceInternal, when trying to load an image

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webclient, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting this error

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.SetSourceInternal(Stream streamSource)
```

When I'm trying to load an image like this:

```
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://zomerparkfeest.nl/uploads/" + currentItem.photo), webClient);
```

And in opReadAsync:

```
private void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
        {
            BitmapImage bitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitMapImage.SetSource(e.Result);
            image.Source = bitMapImage;
            loadingImagePBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            imageLocked = false;
        }
 }
```

I don't always get this exception, it's mostly after loading a lot of images. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Use this by Memory stream this would work fine
   private void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled)
            {
                BitmapImage bitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
                Stream content=e.Result;
                           MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                            content.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                            memoryStream.Position = 0;
                            byte[] buffer = null;

                            if (memoryStream != null && memoryStream.Length > 0)
                            {
                                BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
                                buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)memoryStream.Length);
                            }
                            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
                            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                             bitMapImage.SetSource(stream);
                image.Source = bitMapImage;
                loadingImagePBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                imageLocked = false;
            }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this solved the issue. A nullpointer occured some time after I tried it but I can't seem to recreate it. Thanks again!